# Why TeXstudio closes immediately after updating packages with MiKTeX?

Tags: miktex, texstudio

I´m having this problem. After updating packages with MiKTeX (because TeXstudio was not showing the reference page with the `\printbibliography` command) I restart my laptop. Now when I clik on TeXstudio icon it opens and immediately closes.

Anybody having the same problem?
How can I fix it?

Comment: I reinstalled TeXstudio and the problem continues :(

Comment: You should probably contact the TeXstudio creators if you find a log file with information about a crash. Where you find a log file, depends on your Operating System.
Have you tried the portable version of TeXstudio? Maybe some remains of your old installation is causing trouble.